# How to handle keyboard operation on selenium chrome browser running on virtual ubuntu 22

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am trying to select "OK" button against my browser certificate pop-up using robot class. The same piece of code works well on windows but failing on ubuntu.

Code:

```
public void load() {
    setUrl();
    Thread threadNavigation = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            driver.navigate().to(url);

        }
    };

    Thread threadCertificateHandler = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.delay(2000);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    // Start the threads.
    threadNavigation.start();
    threadCertificateHandler.start();

    // Wait for them both to finish
    try {
        threadNavigation.join();
        threadCertificateHandler.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Code Explanation:** As soon as url is navigated using selenium, a certificate pop-up is displayed before page is loaded. The approach I have used here - 1 thread used here to get application url and another thread is used to handle the pop-up.

Attaching screenshot of the pop-up.
[image]

**ChromeDriver Init Code:**

```
public void getStandaloneHubNodeServerDriver(String browserType,String platformType, String url) throws MalformedURLException  {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    logger.log(Level.INFO, () -> "Setting browser address @: " + url);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Arrays.asList("disable-popup-blocking"));
    //threadLocalDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url),options));
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url),options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

The same code works like a charm on local windows but when executed on remote VM running on linux, it does not perform the "Enter" event. Is there's any alternative to Robot class that can be used for linux?

Answer (score 0):

Robot class is generally inconsistent as it blindly performs keyboard or mouse actions. I have figured out a solution to select the browser certificate without Robot class. This works only on Firefox though. If you are happy to switch from Chrome to Firefox, try the below code:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addArguments("-profile");
options.addArguments("C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/zyz.default");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

In the above code, driver instance is loaded with the default Firefox browser profile. This profile will contain the certificate which will be accepted automatically and pop-up will not even be triggered. Try this and see if you can get away from using Robot class.

Comment: I am using docker approach with browser image running on my ubuntu VM. How to make it work with firefox container?

Comment: Sorry my knowledge in docker is limited. You will have to work your way out to use Firefox by doing exactly how you have done with chrome.

Comment: No issues Shawn. Thanks